# My Main Query Modification is Messing up my dynamic main - why?

Tags: wp-query, menus, pre-get-posts

This has been very difficult to track and I have enabled only the plugins I need (ACF and my own plugins that deal with content type creation).

I noticed that on some pages, my menus were gone, this are menus loaded from header.php so it's the same code.

I do modify the main query, by hooking onto **pre_get_posts**. For instance, when a post type is of a certain type, I modify the main query like so:

```
else if ( is_post_type_archive( 'people' ) ) {
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
    // Bug: Line below causes the menu not to show.
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'display_order' );
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
}
```

As the comment suggests, this line is the one that causes the whole menu to disappear:

```
    // Bug: Line below causes the menu not to show.
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'display_order' );
```

I then went over to my **wp_nav_menu** invocation and drilled onto it with the debugger. It came down to **post.php** in these two line (around line number 1960 as of 25 Apr 2019) :

```
$get_posts = new WP_Query;
return $get_posts->query( $r );
```

When I enable the line that causes the bug, **$get_posts->query( $r );** brings nothing back, when I disable it, it brings the menus back.

I compared the contents if $get_posts in its creation and of $r when bug is present and when bug is not present and the contents are exactly the same, which baffles the hell out of me.

This must be a global variable that is dirty b/c of my code and it messes up the query, so I'm probably missing a wp_reset_query() somewhere but I cannot figure where.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

For reference, here are the output I mention of the variables:

**Working Output**

- https://link.scorpiotek.com/y8b
- https://link.scorpiotek.com/cuj

**Bug Output**

- https://link.scorpiotek.com/3lq
- https://link.scorpiotek.com/5ui

Comment: what's $r in *return $get_posts->query( $r );*

Comment: $r (without bug) -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gebnyiFzmTPxt9XAsyjuSyaBk6ewGjvF/view
$r (with bug) -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/13FF-_pvwXT-rsIAdd-cE5sIclAi7y6l5/view

(same output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for that is pretty straight forward...

In you code (at least in the part you’ve showed) the only condition you check is:

```
if ( is_post_type_archive( 'people' ) )
```

So when you’re on archive for people, this condition will be true for every WP_Query on that page.

Let’s say you have some “Latest news” section in the footer and they’re retrieved with WP_Query. `pre_get_post` filter will get run for such WP_Query too and the condition above will be still true.

And menu is another example, because it’s also retrieved using WP_Query...

That’s why it’s important to check if `$query->is_main_query()` also, if you want to modify only the main query.

So your code should look something like this:

```
else if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_post_type_archive( 'people' ) ) {
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
// Bug: Line below causes the menu not to show.
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'display_order' );
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
}
```

PS. Of course there is possibility that the same should be applied for other parts of that if statement, so the structure of that if may get changed...

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought of that and tried it as soon as I posted my question but the menu keeps disappearing even when I use $query->is_main_query(). In case you'd like to see my entire query code, it's here-> https://link.scorpiotek.com/p5y

Comment: You were absolutely right, not sure what I was testing when I wrote the code, thanks!